# Pop and insert value in permutation matrix by doing multiplication

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, permutation, matrix-multiplication

I would like to pop() and then insert() value in the permutation matrix.
I can achieve it by just doing simple remove(), moveMemory(), insert() but the question is. Is it achievable with the multiplication of the permutation matrix? I only know how to swap columns/rows but nothing more.

Comment: It's certainly possible when the output from the multiplication is a new matrix. Doing it in-place probably isn't possible.

Comment: It doesn't have to be done in place. If you have any idea I would be glad

Comment: @PiotrK. Can you share one example?